# How can I solve problem installing pusher/pusher-php-server using composer in laravel 7?

Tags: laravel

When trying to install pusher using composer on my laravel app, i got the following errors :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires pusher/pusher-php-server ^7.0 -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-php-server[7.0.0].
    - pusher/pusher-php-server 7.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.2 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[dev-master, 7.2.0, 7.3.0, 7.4.x-dev (alias of dev-master)] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^6.3).

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vghwa.jpg)

How to solve it, please help...

Comment: Please, share your `composer.json` file.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa - Here's an 'composer.json` link to _(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rTA_QRv5amAVl4ujcXZAYU6_OL-EApXp/view?usp=sharing)_ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears like one of your dependencies (`pusher/pusher-php-server`) requires `guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.2` yet your `composer.json` file is constrained to `guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3`.

#### STEP 1

Try upgrading `guzzle` by finding and editing your `composer.json` file to:

`"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2.0",`

### STEP 2

After that, run in your terminal:

`composer update guzzlehttp/guzzle`

You should see something *no exactly* but similar to:

```php
/*
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Upgrading guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.3 => 7.2.0)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Upgrading guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.3 => 7.2.0): Extracting archive
Generating optimized autoload files
composer/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...
composer/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: laravel/breeze
Discovered Package: laravel/sail
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully.
79 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

*/
```

#### Addendum

Another thing you may want to keep in mind is:

The latest version of [pusher/pusher-php-server v7.0.0](https://packagist.org/packages/pusher/pusher-php-server#7.0.0) **requires** `php: ^7.3|^8.0` yet your current `composer.json` file is constrained to `"php": "^7.2.5",`.

In this case, you may have to install a lower version of `pusher-php-server` that will work fine with your current *composer.json* file *PHP* version constraint. i.e:

You may work with [*pusher-php-server v6.1.0*](https://packagist.org/packages/pusher/pusher-php-server#6.1.0) that supports/requires `php: ^7.2.5|^8.0`

That would be installed by running the command below  in your terminal:

`composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "^6.1.0"`